# Project management - replacement to JIRA which wouldn't support SVN

Tags: svn, project-management, issue-tracking

We were working with JIRA and SVN and it was great.
I love the way JIRA works and think.

Unfortunately JIRA will [stop supporting SVN on Oct 2013](https://go-dvcs.atlassian.com/display/EOL/Source+Review+Bundle+End+of+Service). I do want to continue with SVN.

I need a tool that supports mainly the followings:

1. Task blocking (I should be able to mark task as blocking other tasks and being blocked by others)
2. SVN integration plugin - easy as it is in JIRA

Which one should I use? I am looking for an hosted solution

I read the comparison table in Wikipedia, but experience would be better

Comment: To support svn (or most) version control in jira, you shouzld use fisheye which brings advanced repository support to jira

Comment: @Bruce Jira wouldn't support it as Oct 2013

Comment: https://go-dvcs.atlassian.com/display/EOL/Source+Review+Bundle+End+of+Service

Comment: You might want to add that you're looking for a hosted solution. With downloaded solutions (hosted by you), it would still work, I'm using it here.

Comment: Thanks. Is it your own server or you host it somewhere? I thought to buy storage for hosting in GoDaddy

Comment: It's hosted in my company, not available on the web. It requires quite good hardware to host Jira + confluence + fisheye on same swerver (always depending on your activity and size, obviously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of pure local solution (your SVN-server, your ProjectTracker)

- [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/) (mostly bugtracker, but with RoadMap|Changelog, Related Tickets, Custom Fields it *can be* considered as some type of ALM-tool) + [source-integration plugin](http://noswap.com/projects/source-integration) for Mantis

Hosted solution

- [Assembla](https://www.assembla.com) with internal Subversion tool or External Subversion tool + Tickets with custom fields (and "Blocking Tickets"+"Blocked tickets" in tickets reports, automagically appeared)

Comment: BTW, Assembla has BEFORE in ticket management so it's sort of an indication for a task that blocks others